# Search API - create document and index

Tags: google-app-engine, search, full-text-search

I need help in the search API

I am Brazilian and I'm using the google translator to communicate.

My question is:
For each item in the datastore persisted I create a document and an index? To use the Search API
or 
What better way to full-text-search ?

Comment: +1 for asking for help in your second language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to use the search api and search over the documents you need to create:

- one only index for all the documents
- one document for each entity you want to be able to search for
- one search field for each property for each entity you want find

[here a basic tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2)

Comment: you have to create a search.Document for each one of them and then put them all together or in batches if you have a lot of them. just read the documentation and you will find the answers.